# In Nexus 2.7+ is there a way to view installed plugins via REST API?

Tags: nexus

In previous versions of Nexus you could look at the output of http:///nexus/service/local/status and this would give you a list of installed plugins.

However, in Nexus 2.7 that functionality is no longer present. Has this been moved to a new location or is there another way of accessing it.

I realize that it can be viewed in the Plugin Console from the UI but this is for automation purpose so manual checks won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following REST API will return a list of plugins and links to other API docs:

- [Nexus Plugin Console Plugin REST API](https://repository.sonatype.org/nexus-plugin-console-plugin/default/docs/index.html)

Example URL:

```
http://localhost:8081/nexus/service/local/plugin_console/plugin_infos
```